# Estimate dispersion parameters in negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, maximum-likelihood, inference, negative-binomial-distribution

A popular parameterization of the negative binomial distribution is by $\mu$ and $r$, which represent mean and dispersion, respectively. The probability mass function states:
$$
\text{P(x = k)} = \frac{\Gamma(r + k)}{k! \Gamma(r)} \cdot \Bigg( \frac{r}{r + \mu} \Bigg)^r \Bigg( \frac{\mu}{r + \mu} \Bigg)^k
$$

A common way to infer population parameter $r, \mu$ from samples is to use maximum likelihood estimation.

There is a relationship between $\mu, \sigma^2, r$, which is
$$
r = \frac{\mu^2}{\sigma^2 - \mu}
$$

I was wondering if this would be a reasonable way to infer population parameters:

1. calculate sample mean $\bar x$ and sample variance $s^2$
2. infer the population dispersion as $$\hat r = \frac{\bar x^2}{s^2 - \bar x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a reasonable way.  It is called a "Method of Moments" (MoM) estimator, as it uses the first two sample moments to calculate the estimate.  Often, for the negative binomial distribution, it's actually a pretty good estimator - but by no means always.

Having said this, though, it can easily be, especially with small samples and not much overdispersion, that $s^2 \leq \bar{x}$, in which case you have a problem.  In this case, the MLE doesn't exist either.  Other estimators can be found in
[Estimating the Negative Binomial Dispersion Parameter](https://scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=ajms.2010.1.15).

Comment: For the method of moments estimator, I will need to calculate sample variance first. Should I use "n-1" or "n" as the denominator? I understand the sample variance should be corrected for normal distribution, but should I also correct for negative binomial distribution?